# Excel Macro, Find All Duplicates in Column and see coorisponding value

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

**Excel Macro that will do the following:**

*To Find All Duplicates in (ColumnA) and to see if (ColumnB) contains a certain value and run a code against that result.*

**How i would write the code if i could:**

```
If (ColumnB) .value in that (group of duplicates_found) in any row is "R-".value then

Keep the row with "R-".value and delete the rest. Else if "R-".value not exist and "M-".value Exist, delete all duplicates except first "R-".value found.

Else

If duplicate group contains "R-".value more than once, keep first "R-".value row found and delete the rest

Endif

Continue to loop until all duplicates found and run through above code.
```

*^^sorry if not making sense up there:
I guess we can select first group of duplicates and run check on it like described below.^^*

**in this group all would be deleted, except one row.**

[image]

**(in this group we could specify to keep first "R-".value found and delete rest)**

[image]

**(this group has a "R-".value so the "M-".value gets deleted.)**

[image]

**(this group has a "R-".value so the "M-".value gets deleted.)**

[image]

***Code I used*** once to delete all "M-".value(s), hoping to reverse to do above as described per a first group found and to continue:

```
Sub DeleteRowWithContents()
Dim rFnd As Range, dRng As Range, rFst As String, myList, ArrCnt As Long
myList = Array("M-")

    For ArrCnt = LBound(myList) To UBound(myList)
        With Range("B1:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
            Set rFnd = .Find(What:=myList(ArrCnt), _
                             LookIn:=xlValues, _
                             LookAt:=xlPart, _
                             SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                             SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                             MatchCase:=True)

            If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then

                rFst = rFnd.Address
                Do
                    If dRng Is Nothing Then
                        Set dRng = Range("A" & rFnd.Row)
                    Else
                        Set dRng = Union(dRng, Range("A" & rFnd.Row))
                    End If

                    Set rFnd = .FindNext(After:=rFnd)

                Loop Until rFnd.Address = rFst
            End If

            Set rFnd = Nothing
        End With
    Next ArrCnt

    If Not dRng Is Nothing Then dRng.EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

this code goes through column and finds duplicates and highlights them. Maybe this could be rewritten to highlight each duplicate a separate color?

```
Sub MarkDuplicates()

Dim iWarnColor As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim rngCell As Variant


Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Select ' area to check '
Set rng = Selection
iWarnColor = xlThemeColorAccent2

For Each rngCell In rng.Cells
    vVal = rngCell.Text
    If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, vVal) = 1) Then
        rngCell.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
    Else
        rngCell.Interior.ColorIndex = iWarnColor
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

this code Looks for colored cells a specific RGB color and selects them, maybe for each group that is colored differently select that color and do a function on it?

```
Sub SelectColoredCells()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lColor As Long
    Dim rColored As Range

    'Select the color by name (8 possible)
    'vbBlack, vbBlue, vbGreen, vbCyan,
    'vbRed, vbMagenta, vbYellow, vbWhite
    lColor = RGB(156, 0, 6)

    'If you prefer, you can use the RGB function
    'to specify a color
    'Default was lColor = vbBlue
    'lColor = RGB(0, 0, 255)

    Set rColored = Nothing
    For Each rCell In Selection
        If rCell.Interior.Color = lColor Then
            If rColored Is Nothing Then
                Set rColored = rCell
            Else
                Set rColored = Union(rColored, rCell)
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If rColored Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cells match the color"
    Else
        rColored.Select
        MsgBox "Selected cells match the color:" & _
            vbCrLf & rColored.Address
    End If
    Set rCell = Nothing
    Set rColored = Nothing
End Sub
```

This has had me tied down to the computer for a week now and i cant seem to resolve it.

Comment: So you have code pasted here, have you adapted it to your needs? Is it doing something it shouldn't? Is it not doing something it should?

Comment: No im trying to write code based off the description in the beginning, the code here is the code i think i can reverse engineer to make what i want.

Comment: Well, have you tried that yet? Give that a go and come back if you run into any specific problems.

Comment: Hey, just edited the post to make it more understandable. 

I have tried and this post is a result of me trying.

Comment: I understand your goal, it's an interesting exercise and can be done without too much trouble. The point I'm making is - you've collected code and run it, but you haven't demonstrated that you've tried to cobble together an attempt at doing what you want. Maybe you've managed to identify duplicates, but you don't know how to remember them to compare column B. Maybe you are trying to delete rows, but your loop ends up skipping..

Comment: Hey ill be honest, at this point i dont have much other than a concept, i would really appreciate any help or guidance. (the week part was me trying to assemble this concept. Finding all those example codes and making sure they work)

Comment: I added in your images and cleaned up some of the text.  Hopefully everything is still in line with your original question.  I also removed the [macro] tag.  It is not intended for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer, it's a complicated one, but I took the question as a challenge to improve my use of particular methods in VBA.

This goes through your cells and creates an array of the results as you like.

I was using numbers in my testing, so every time you see `str(Key)` you might just need to remove the `str()` function.

This results in printing the array to columns `D:E` rather than removing rows from your list. You could just clear columns `A:B` and then print to `"A1:B" & dict.Count` - that would have the same effect, essentially.

```vb
Sub test()
Dim dict As Object
Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim strA As String

For i = 1 To lastrow
    strA = Cells(i, 1)
    dict(strA) = 1
Next

Dim vResult() As Variant
ReDim vResult(dict.Count - 1, 1)

Dim x As Integer
x = 0



Dim strB As String
Dim strKey As String

For Each Key In dict.keys
    vResult(x, 0) = Key
    x = x + 1
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
        strA = Str(c)
        strB = c.Offset(0, 1).Value
          If strA = Str(Key) Then
            If Left(strB, 1) = "r" Then
                vResult(x - 1, 1) = c.Offset(, 1)
                GoTo label
            End If
           End If

    Next
    If vResult(x - 1, 1) = Empty Then
        For Each c In Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
            strA = Str(c)
            If strA = Str(Key) Then
                vResult(x - 1, 1) = c.Offset(, 1)
                GoTo label
            End If
        Next
    End If
label:
Next
Range("D1:E" & dict.Count).Value = vResult()
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey, Ill let you know when i have tested this out. I Really Want to Thank you for pursuing this as a challenge and helping me out with a tough problem.

Comment: Right, I used numbers, you need to remove all `str()` functions, I mentioned that in the answer